# GitHub Actions: environment variables not processing under "with" keyword

Tags: yaml, github-actions

##### MAIN ISSUE

While experimenting with github actions, faced an issue such that the default environment variables passed to pre-built actions specifically under the `with` syntax didn't getting processed, i.e.

```yaml
    - name: variable check
      uses: external/action-module@v2
      with:
        option1: ${{ secrets.ENV_1 }}
        option2: ${GITHUB_DEF_VARIABLE}
```

The secrets(`${{ secrets.ENV_1 }}`) getting rendered correctly while the [github-actions default variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables#default-environment-variables)(`${GITHUB_DEF_VARIABLE}`) failed to render.

##### BACKGROUND AND REAL CASES

Showing some cases,

When calling an ansible playbook with github actions,

```yaml
    - name: Check ansible playbook execution with module
      uses: dawidd6/action-ansible-playbook@v2
      with:
        playbook: ${{ secrets.ANSIBLE_ROOT }}/Playbooks/ping.yml
        inventory: ${{ secrets.ANSIBLE_INVENTORY }}
        options: |
          --extra-vars github_workpath=${GITHUB_WORKSPACE} other_var=${{ secrets.EXTA_VAR }}
```

The issue is that the default env variable didn't getting processed (`${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}`), but the secrets rendering without any issues (`${{ secrets.EXTA_VAR }}`)

Tried the same by setting an `env:` and then calling `${{ env.VARIABLE }}` but that also not worked,

What finally worked for me was by manually calling playbook with inventory after setting the default variable to a global job `env`.

```yaml
    env:
      project_path: ${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}

    steps:
    - name: Calling Ansible playbook directly
      run: >
        ansible-playbook
        -i ${{ secrets.ANSIBLE_ROOT }}/inventory.yml
        ${{ secrets.ANSIBLE_ROOT }}/Playbooks/ping.yml
        --extra-vars github_workpath=${{ env.project_path }}
```

Now the `${{ env.project_path }}` processed to give the desired output(passing the variable `${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}` direct also failed)

The same issue faced when trying to send Job completion web-hook notification, eg

```yaml
    - name: Mattermost Notification
      uses: komarnitskyi/action-mattermost-notification@v0.1.2-beta
      with:
        webhook: ${{ secrets.MATTERMOST_WEBHOOK_URL }}
        text: "| ${GITHUB_EVENT_NAME} | ${GITHUB_REF##*/} | ${{ job.status }} |"
```

The end text displayed as `${GITHUB_EVENT_NAME} | ${GITHUB_REF##*/}`, but the `${{ job.status }}` rendered correctly as *completed/failed*.. ,

Can somebody explain this behaviour and any workarounds for this issue.

Comment: Is there a reason why you used directly `${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}` instead of `$GITHUB_WORKSPACE` or `${{GITHUB_WORKSPACE}}`? (The documentation usually only show the latest syntaxes, so I wanted to know if you saw an example using only `${` somewhere else. It might work with bash, but I was wondering if at the workflow level the github interpreter would recognized it as well)

Comment: @GuiFalourd thanks for spending time to figure it out,  the syntax works I think github treats `${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}` and `$GITHUB_WORKSPACE` the same, also checked directly, the results
https://imgur.com/a/9yhi1pv
I just use that because of getting quick visual separation for variables in a text.
it works inside a `run` command statement, also in the second ansible example it stores value to the environment and I'm able to display that, issue is with the mentioned cases.

Comment: The problem might be by using this specific syntax as action input (in the `with` field). Because you explained that using `${{` always displayed the variable as expected, but using `${` didn't.

Comment: The `${{ }}` syntax does not works for default environment variables,
like if used `run: echo "${{ GITHUB_EVENT_NAME }}"`
it gives an error,
`Unrecognized named-value: 'GITHUB_EVENT_NAME'. Located at position 1 within expression: GITHUB_EVENT_NAME`
it looks like the `{{ }}` syntax treats contents differently.

the secrets and other git variables only works inside the text fields passed under `with` statement, I've tried changing the syntax

Comment: Using `$GITHUB_EVENT_NAME` directly for default variable didn't work neither when passed under the `with` statement?

Comment: No, not with atleast the cases that is mentioned in the question..for example, the webhook notification it prints `$GITHUB_EVENT_NAME` directly instead of the the event.